How to use PostgrestFilterBuilder from PostgREST without encountering a type error of missing properties that are expected in PostgrestQueryBuilder
First I'm working on a typescript react based project that uses supabase for the backend.
firstly here is my code:
First code image
Second code image
I'm making a resuable component that create or edit a cabin base on the id, if the Id is true it's edits else create.
Here is the code I wrote
 //create and edit the cabin

  let query = supabase.from('cabins') 

  //create
  if(!id) query = query.insert([{...data,image:imageUrl}]);

  //edit 
  if(id) query = query
  .update({...data, image:imageUrl })
  .eq('id', id)
  
  
  const {data:newCabin,error} = await query.select().single()

  if(error) {console.log(error)
    throw new Error("An error occurerd creating a cabin.") 
}

The error i get
Code error.
Here is how the function is been used in code
First image of code implementation
Second image of code implementation
Note I get the required output from my browser and the data even gets updated in my backend, my code hasn't broken but the typscript is still complaning to me. Please what's the best approach to solving this
These are the approach I took
First approach
I ran "@supabase/postgrest-js" command on my terminal.
Second approach
    ...

    let query: PostgrestQueryBuilder<newCabinType>;

    if (!id) {
      query = supabase.from('cabins').insert([{ ...data, image: imageUrl }]);
    } else {
      query = supabase.from('cabins').update({ ...data, image: imageUrl }).eq('id', id);
    }

    const { data: newCabin, error }: PostgrestSingleResponse<newCabinType> = await query.single();

    if (error) {
      throw new Error("An error occurred creating/editing a cabin.");
    }

    ...


Third approach
I have explicitly defined the types on the declared query variable, but got more errors on that approach

let query: PostgrestQueryBuilder<newCabinType, any, "cabins", any>;
 let query: PostgrestQueryBuilder<newCabinType, unknown>;

I expected these solution to work but nothing worked

After months of trying I finally found a solution, here's how I went around the whole thing.
Firstly, I Removed the separate let query assignment and directly performed insert or update operations, storing the result in query which was later modified as query result queryResult.
By me avoiding reassigning query, I prevented TypeScript from needing to handle the type differences between PostgrestQueryBuilder and PostgrestFilterBuilder.
Updated code:
  let queryResult;

  if(!id) {
    //CREATE
    queryResult = await supabase.from('cabins').insert([{...data,image:imageUrl}])
  }else{
    //EDIT
    queryResult = await supabase.from('cabins').update({...data, image:imageUrl}).eq('id',id).select().single();
  }

  const {data:newCabin, error} = queryResult;

Old code
let query = supabase.from('cabins') 

  //create
  if(!id) query = query.insert([{...data,image:imageUrl}]);

  //edit 
  if(id) query = query
  .update({...data, image:imageUrl })
  .eq('id', id)
  
  
  const {data:newCabin,error} = await query.select().single()


     

